# How do I delete a Firestore Document from a List in SwiftUI

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui, swiftui-list

Here is my view model

```
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct Todo: Codable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var todoDetais: String?
}
```

This is how I'm showing the list ignore the typo in "details".

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.todos, id: \.self) { todo in
                VStack{
                    Text(todo.todoDetais!)
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: delete)
        }
```

My fetch data and mapping.

```
    func fetchData() {
    db.collection("todos").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
        guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
        }
        
        self.todos = documents.map { (QueryDocumentSnapshot)  -> Todo in
            let data = QueryDocumentSnapshot.data()
            let todoDetails = data["todo"] as? String ?? ""
            
            return Todo(todoDetais: todoDetails)
        }
    }
}
```

The delete logic, I can remove from a list but how do I delete from Firestore?

```
    func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    viewModel.todos.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    
    //I need to delete a firestore document at the index im removing at?
    
}
```

Comment: You'll need to keep a mapping from the offset of each item in the list to its ID in Firestore. Once you have that [deleting the document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/delete-data) is easy. I also recommend at that point only deleting it from the database, as that will in itself then force a repaint of the UI through SwiftUI.

Comment: the ViewModel already has a wrapper for the @DocumentID I'm not quite sure through code what I'm supposed to do. I've been stuck on it for a while

Comment: @JustinComstock you haven't shown your view model's code or your todo model code, so it's a little hard to say what has to happen. You can map the offsets to todos by doing this: `offsets.map { viewModel.todos[$0] }`. Can you figure out how to delete them from there?

Comment: @jnpdx I added the viewmodel code, I can't figure out the deleting portion of this. What would the code look like with the offset and the delete?

Comment: You haven't added the view model code, but I do see the `Todo` model. I'll try adding an answer based on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the offsets to your `Todo` models by doing this:

```
offsets.map { viewModel.todos[$0] }
```

So, your delete function might look something like this:

```
func delete(at offsets: IndexSet) {
  offsets.map { viewModel.todos[$0] }.forEach { todo in 
    guard let todoID = todo.id else { return }
    db.collection("todos").document(todoID).delete() { err in
      if let err = err {
        print("Error removing document: \(err)")
      } else {
        print("Document successfully removed!")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you had a bunch, you could look into batching the requests, but this should get you started.

Comment: Having trouble getting this solution to work, what is "todoID" field?

Comment: I don't know what you're referring to. Do you mean where I have `todoID = todo.id`? That's because you have `id` declared as an optional on your `Todo` model.

Comment: Yes. when I use a breakpoint it looks like a UUID so the problem here is that I need the DocumentID.

Comment: What does your document ID look like? I don't have any knowledge about your Firestore structure and what your document IDs do or do not look like.

Comment: "miEVaGRQ12phsINusyox" I think it's part of the mapping that I'm missing, I put @DocumentID for the todoDataModel but it's not enough to assign it. When I delete a document I need to have a reference to it based on the offset of the remove.

Comment: Thanks for the help I figured it out. I needed to map the ID to the DocumentID I figured that was my issue but I somehow managed to get it right. 
"let id = QueryDocumentSnapshot.documentID"

Comment: @JustinComstock -- I was just about to come back and write that. Glad you got it!